# Wordpress settings not getting saved

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am new to wordpress am trying to develop a wordpress plugin but while adding a setting section am facing problem my option is not getting save to database please help.

```
function rclk_settings_section() {
        echo "Check to enable";
    }

    function rclk_settings_output() {           
        $status = get_option('rclk_sec');
        ?>
        <label>Enable
        <input type='radio' name='rclk_sec' value="1" <?php     echo ($status == '1')?'checked': ' ';  ?>>
        </label>

        <label>Disable
        <input type='radio' name='rclk_sec' value="0" <?php     echo ($status == '0')?'checked': ' ';  ?>>
        </label>
        <?php
    }

    function disable_rclk_settings_page() {             
        //create settings 
        $section_group = "reading"; $section_name = "rclk_sec";
        register_setting($sections_group, $section_name); //create section of page 
        $settings_section = "default"; $page = $section_group; add_settings_section($settings_section, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', "rclk_settings_section", $page); 
        //create section fields 
    add_settings_field($section_name, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', 'rclk_settings_output', $page, $settings_section);
    }
add_action('admin_init', 'disable_rclk_settings_page');
```

Comment: where you save these data?

Comment: i am adding this section in reading sub menu which is under settings main menu since am adding this to reading page as a section wordpress will save it automatically with option name right

Comment: disable_rclk_settings_page function not there in your code

Comment: function disable_rclk_settings_page() {
    //create settings
    $section_group = "reading";
    $section_name = "rclk_sec";
    register_setting($sections_group, $section_name);
    //create section of page
    $settings_section = "default";
    $page = $section_group;
    add_settings_section($settings_section, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', "rclk_settings_section", $page);
    //create section fields
    add_settings_field($section_name, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', 'rclk_settings_output', $page, $settings_section);
}

Comment: this code is above the code i have specified in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

```
function rclk_settings_section() {
        echo "Check to enable";
    }

    function rclk_settings_output() {           
        $status = get_option('rclk_sec');
        ?>
        <label>Enable
        <input type='radio' name='rclk_sec' value="1" <?php     echo ($status == '1')?'checked': ' ';  ?>>
        </label>

        <label>Disable
        <input type='radio' name='rclk_sec' value="0" <?php     echo ($status == '0')?'checked': ' ';  ?>>
        </label>
        <?php
    }

    function disable_rclk_settings_page() {             
        //create settings 
        $section_group = "reading"; $section_name = "rclk_sec";
        register_setting($sections_group, $section_name); //create section of page 
        $settings_section = "default"; $page = $section_group; add_settings_section($settings_section, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', "rclk_settings_section", $page); 
        //create section fields 
    add_settings_field($section_name, 'Disable Right Click and CTRL+C', 'rclk_settings_output', $page, $settings_section);
    }
add_action('admin_init', 'disable_rclk_settings_page');
```

Comment: no i havn't missed it its there check line number 4 in disable_rclk_settings_page function

Comment: i mean am getting 2 sections of same option

Comment: even after selecting disable its storing 1 itself

Comment: Yes above the code is displaying double times. before its working fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131176/discussion-between-akshay-k-h-and-vel).

Comment: how to update this option as of now option is not getting updated on changing value in settings page